# Wrong class path while deploying JASIG CAS in JBOSS 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, cas

I'm trying to deploy a CAS web application on JBOSS 7. The package name is `cas-server-webapp-3.4.11.war`.

I'm facing the following error during install:

`09:37:06,951 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/cas-server-webapp-3.4.11]] (MSC service thread 1-5)` 
`Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid 'log4jConfigLocation' parameter: class path resource [log4j.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:/D:/Programming/jboss7/bin/content/cas-server-webapp-3.4.11.war/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml`

Deployment package is located in `D:\Programming\jboss7\standalone\deployments\cas-server-webapp-3.4.11.war`, but obviously JBOSS tries to resolve paths to `D:/Programming/jboss7/bin/content/cas-server-webapp-3.4.11.war`.

How I can change this path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is the following:

In persistence.xml put the following content:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="CasPersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl</class>
    <class>org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl</class>
    <class>org.jasig.cas.ticket.ServiceTicketImpl</class>
    <class>org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.JpaLockingStrategy$Lock</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

In web.xml instead of:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

put

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF\classes\log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Hope this will help & save time to others.

Answer (score 2):

For CAS 1.5 log4j configuration is defined in WEB-INF/cas.properties file where you define the location.

I used this configuration:

`log4j.config.location=${jboss.server.base.dir}/deployments/cas-server-webapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml`

However, when application server doesn't unpack war during deployment it doesn't work anyway because this file is not on filesystem. So the easiest way is to disable initialization of this bean at all by deleting src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/log4jConfiguration.xml file.

Also this issue is relevant to this [topic](https://issues.jasig.org/browse/CAS-1080).